# SQL - Calcular horas totales diarias de uso

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

agradeceria muchisimo la ayuda para resolver este problema:
Tengo una tabla en sql server donde tengo los siguientes datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito hacer una query que me saque las horas totales de uso que tuvo cada maquina por día.
En el ejemplo la maquina MAQ1 se uso 12.50 hrs en el día (de 7 a 11 y de 12 a 20:30).
La MAQ2 se uso 11.5 horas. Si hago un SUM de horas me da que la MAQ1 trabajo 14 y la MAQ2 13.5 lo cual seria incorrecto.

la fecha es tipo de dato DATE (yyyy-mm-dd) y las horas de inicio y de fin son TIME hh:mm (horas:minutos).
las horas totales estan como float
La tabla es un ejemplo, en la base de datos tengo esa estructura pero multiplicado por 120 maquinas y por todos los dias del año.
gracias

Comment: Bienvenido Wintry a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Agrega a tu pregunta, la consulta en código de lo que intentaste hasta ahora.

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 1):

podrias usar `TIMEDIFF` , `SELECT TIMEDIFF("07:00:00", "11:00:00")` para sacar la diferencia de horas y asi en tu columna de horas totales no se redondee a un entero si no a un flotante y puedas agregar la media hora

Otra cosa es como estas haciendo la consulta?, porque veo que para la Maquina 1 tienes 4 valores asignados

4
3
5
2

Me imagino que haces la consulta algo asi

```
SELECT Sum(HORASTOTALES) FROM Tabla1 WHERE MAQUINA='MAQ1'
```

Esto hara que sume todas las columnas que tenga asignado MAQ1
por eso te da 14

Comment: Creo que el problema no es que se redondean las horas sino que según entiendo el solo quiere sumar los rangos mencionados (de 7 a 11 y de 12 a 20:30). Saludos.

Comment: no es el problema lo que vos comentas, mi problema es que no puedo sacar cuantas horas trabajo un equipo cuando tengo mas de una persona en el mismo momento usandola.